# How to use subprocess.Popen() instead of os.popen() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

Since os.popen is deprecated, I wanted to use subprocess.Popen (and also because it is a lot more robust in every sense). I had this initially but can't figure out how to make the appropriate transition.

```
PID_FILE = 'process.pid'
if os.path.exists( PID_FILE ):
    pid = int(open( PID_FILE,'rb').read().rstrip('\n'))
    pinfo = os.popen('ps %i' % pid).read().split('\n')
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: I saw it but honestly could not relate to it since I'm still a beginner in Python and slowly progressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `subprocess.Popen` to create a new process, with its stdout redirected to a PIPE, in text mode and then read its stdout.

**Python version >= 3.6**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
with Popen(f'ps {pid}'.split(), stdout=PIPE, text=True) as proc:
    pinfo = proc.stdout.readlines()
```

As you have requested for python2.7, I have given the code. But remember that python2.7 has reached EOL and you should be using python3.x

**Python version = 2.7**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(f'ps {pid}'.split(), stdout=PIPE)
pinfo = proc.stdout.readlines()
```

Refer [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3) for more information

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Tried it, throwing the following error:  

with Popen(f'ps {pid}'.split(), stdout=PIPE, text=True) as proc:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Looks like you are using python version < 3.6 . Just change `f'ps {pid}'` to `'ps %i' % pid'` as you had in your code. But I strongly would encourage you to upgrade to latest version of python

Comment: Got you. I'm using 2.7 you got that right. Sure I will upgrade It thanks!

Comment: I'm using this now:
`with Popen(('ps %i' % pid).split(), shell=True, stdout=PIPE) as proc:`
And getting this error *AttributeError: __exit__*
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Using Popen as a context manager (that is using it with `with`) is supported only from python 3.2. For python2 you can `proc = Popen(('ps %i' % pid).split(), stdout=PIPE); pinfo = proc.stdout.readlines()`

Comment: But remember that python2.7 has reached EOL and you should be really using python3.x

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help and inputs. You're the MVP. Works like a charm. And I'll surely be upgrading to 3.x asap.